# malloc inside function / call-by-reference / valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, pass-by-reference

I'm not very professional on C and so I get a problem with valgrind.

I want to read in an input from command-line.

If I try it this way it works fine.

```
//call the function
char *command = getUserInput();


//function
char *getUserInput()
{ 
  char *buffer = NULL;
  char *temp = NULL;
  unsigned int count = 0;
  unsigned int lenght = 10;
  char character = 0;

  buffer = malloc((lenght+1)*sizeof(char));
  if(buffer == NULL)
  {
    // printf(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEM);
    // return EXIT_OUT_OF_MEM;
  }

  while((character = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    if(count == lenght)
    {
      lenght += 10;
      temp = realloc(buffer,lenght*sizeof(char));
      if(temp != NULL)
        {
          buffer = temp;
        }
      else
        {
          free (buffer);
          // printf(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEM);
          // return EXIT_OUT_OF_MEM; 
        }
    }

    buffer[count] = character;
    count++;

  }
  buffer[count] = '\0';

  return buffer;
}
```

But I cant geht an error-returnvalue.

If I try it in the way by call-by-reference i get some valgrind error I don't understand.
And I know, in this example-function-call I don't request the return-value.

```
//call function
char *command = NULL;
getUserInput(command);

//function
int getUserInput(char *name)
{ 
  char *temp = NULL;
  unsigned int count = 0;
  unsigned int lenght = 10;
  char character = 0;

  name = malloc((lenght+1)*sizeof(char));
  checkMemory(name);

  while((character = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    if(count == lenght)
    {
      lenght += 10;
      temp = realloc(name,lenght*sizeof(char));
      if(temp != NULL)
        {
          name = temp;
        }
      else
        {
          free (name);
          printf(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY_MESSAGE);
          return ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; 
        }
    }

    name[count] = character;
    count++;

  }
  name[count] = '\0';

  return RETURN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Commandhandler-Line 1199 is `if (strcmp(command, "thing_to_compare") == 0)`

Valgrind:

```
==23886== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==23886==    at 0x40256BB: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==23886==    by 0x8049B39: commandHandler (assa.c:1199)
==23886==    by 0x8049D6C: main (assa.c:1295)
==23886==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==23886==    at 0x8049B00: commandHandler (assa.c:1189)
==23886== 
==23886== Invalid read of size 1
==23886==    at 0x40256BB: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==23886==    by 0x8049B39: commandHandler (assa.c:1199)
==23886==    by 0x8049D6C: main (assa.c:1295)
==23886==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I totally don't know where the problem is.

kind regards
Philipp

Comment: It says that the problem is in a function called `commandHandler`. How do you expect us to say anything reasonable about that function if you don't show it to us?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the commandHandler. I edited the post.

Comment: `command` is NULL, that is the error. There is nothing like call by reference in C. You sent the value of command to the function and if it is changed there, it is a local copy which is changed not the original variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getUserInput` has no way to change the value of `command`, as all functions are pass-by-value in C.  Therefore, when you get to all your `strcmp` functions, you are dereferencing that `NULL` pointer causing all sorts of bad things.

If you want `getUserInput` to be able to change the value of `command`, you must pass the address of `command` to the function (which means the function must then take a `char**` argument).

Comment: Thank you, so now i have to pass the value like this? `getUserInput(&command);` and in function `int getUserInput(char **name)`?  
  
The thing I don't understand is how to access `name` inside the function. Change every `name` to `*name`? If I do this, I get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: When you get to assigning individual characters, you'll have to do something like `(*name)[count]` to keep the order of operations in line.